# rsyslog template - parse failure in regular expression

Tags: regex, rsyslog

I am trying to structure logs from my D-Link DAP-2310 in a rsyslog server. It has a non-standard log format and my idea is to fix that with regex in a rsyslog template. When I parse the rsyslog.conf with rsyslogd -N1 the result is really depressing.

The msg data item looks like `AA:BB:CC:DD:EE] [app-name] log message`
The first part is a mac address where the first part “[00:” is placed in another data item, don't ask why. Part two “[app-name]” is the application/instance sending the message. Last part “log message” is the logged action.

The interesting parts are i) app-name and ii) log message.

I have validated following regular expression at http://www.rsyslog.com/regex/ and both of them works like a charm.

1. \[(.+)\]
2. \[.+\](.+)

The full template declaration look like:

```
template(name=”AP_tmpl” type=”list”) {   
    property(name=”timestamp”)    
    constant(value=” “)   
    property(name=”hostname”)
    constant(value=” “)   
    property(name=”msg” 
        regex.type=”ERE” 
        regex.submatch=”1”    
        regex.expression=”\[(.+)\]--end”
        regex.nomatchmode=”BLANK”
    )   
    constant(value=” “)
    property(name=”msg” 
        regex.type=”ERE”
        regex.submatch=”1”
        regex.expression=”\[.+\](.+)$--end”   
        regex.nomatchmode=”BLANK”
    )    
    constant(value=”\n“) 
}
```

When I parse the conf file it complain about escape characters.

```
tobias@ubuntutest:~$ sudo rsyslogd -N1
rsyslogd: version 7.4.4, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/41-AP.conf, on or before line 20: invalid character '"' in object definition - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/41-AP.conf, on or before line 20: invalid character '\' in object definition - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/41-AP.conf, on or before line 20: invalid character '.' in object definition - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/41-AP.conf, on or before line 20: invalid character '*' in object definition - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/41-AP.conf, on or before line 20: invalid character '\' in object definition - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/41-AP.conf, on or before line 20: syntax error on token ']' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
rsyslogd: CONFIG ERROR: could not interpret master config file '/etc/rsyslog.conf'. [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
rsyslogd: run failed with error -2207 (see rsyslog.h or try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 to learn what that number means)
```

I can’t figure out why, the regular expressions are validated without any errors. http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 gives nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Do this `\\[(.+)\\]` and this `\\[.+\\](.+)` work?

Answer (score 3):

When you write `”\[(.+)\]--end”`, `\[` is expected to be a special character (like `\n`), while it is not. To avoid the special use of the backslash, you should escape it with another backslash. So while the real regex are `\[(.+)\]` and `\[.+\](.+)`, the strings you have to use are: `”\\[(.+)\\]”` and `”\\[.+\\](.+)”`.

Also, be careful about the double quotes, you probably want to `"`, and not `”`.

Comment: Parsers without any error, great. But I get no match. I am editing in nano and uses ordinary double quotes (").

Comment: rsyslog really needed perl/sed-like syntax to allow regular expressions to be written more naturally. Either that, or better escaping rules or differentiation between " and ' quotes.