# Rsyslog Template with regex won't verify

Tags: regex, posix, rsyslog

I'm writing a simple template to pull IPs out of a log file being processed by rsyslog.  I've checked the format across their documentation and run the regex through their own regex checker which it validated.  But once I try to run rsyslog's validator across it, it fails with

> *rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/30-waf.conf, on or before line 6: invalid character '"' in object definition - is there
>   an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [v8.16.0 try
>   http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
>  rsyslogd: error during parsing
>   file /etc/rsyslog.d/30-waf.conf, on or before line 6: invalid
>   character '0' in object definition - is there an invalid escape
>   sequence somewhere? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
>
>   rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/30-waf.conf, on or
>   before line 6: invalid character '-' in object definition - is there
>   an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [v8.16.0 try
>   http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
>  rsyslogd: error during parsing
>   file /etc/rsyslog.d/30-waf.conf, on or before line 6: invalid
>   character '9' in object definition - is there an invalid escape
>   sequence somewhere? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
>
>   rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/30-waf.conf, on or
>   before line 6: syntax error on token ']' [v8.16.0 try
>   http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]*

Here is my `.conf` file...

```
template(name="waftest" type="list") {<br>
    property(name="msg"<br>
        regex.type="ERE"<br>
        regex.submatch="0"<br>
        regex.expression="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"<br>
        regex.nomatchmode="BLANK"<br>
        )<br>
}<p>

local1.*action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/FTD/waftest.log");waftest
```

It seems relatively simple and yet I must be missing something.

Comment: see if [this answer helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32660580/9534819)

Comment: Thank you.  Yes,I had reviewed that answer and tried it and it actually made the issue worse with more errors beginning further down... rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/30-waf.conf, on or before line 10: invalid character '(' - is there an invalid escape sequence somewhere? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]
rsyslogd: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/30-waf.conf, on or before line 10: warnings occured in file '/etc/rsyslog.d/30-waf.conf' around line 10 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]

Comment: Never mind.  You're totally right.  That was the answer, I just hadn't followed it all the way through.  Thank you,